# Rewrite the function with single list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Hi I need to rewrite this code using a single list  comprehension

```
result = []
for word in words:
    wordlenpair = (word, len(word))
    result.append(wordlenpair)
return result
```

but I stacked with :

```
result = [wordlenpair  for word in words]
```

and I don't know what to do with this line here:

```
wordlenpair = (word, len(word))
```

Comment: Just replace `wordlenpair` with the tuple. It's just a variable, substitute it for the original expression.

Comment: Hint: shorten the code inside the loop to one line before converting.

Comment: Thanks alot ,now i see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a list of tuples use tuples you want in list comprehension:

```
result = [(word, len(word)) for word in words]
```

Comment: Thank u very much!

Comment: @Hot41 If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.